# Suppose $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is continuous. For $a,b \in f(X)$ with $a \le b$, the interval $[a,b]$ is contained in $f(X)$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be a connected topological space. Suppose $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is continuous.

I want to show that for $a,b \in f(X)$ with $a \le b$, the interval $[a,b]$ is contained in $f(X)$.

I know that $X$ is **connected** means that, if $X = X_1 \cup X_2$ with $X_1 \neq X_2$ open and $X_1 \cap X_2 = \emptyset$ then $X_1 = \emptyset$ and $X_2 = X$ or $X_1 = X$ and $X_2 = \emptyset$.

How can I utilize that $f$ is **continuous** to prove that the whole closed interval $[a,b]$ must be contained in the image $f(X)$ if $a \le b$ are contained in this image ?

Also, I've tried to prove the existence of sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ such that $a_n \rightarrow \infty$ and $b_n \rightarrow -\infty$ for $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Your definition of connected is not quite right.  You also need $X_1$ and $X_2$ to be disjoint.

Comment: I've not edited the definition, thanks. This is the definition as stated on my paper.

Comment: Taking $X = X_1 = X_2$ doesn't satisfy $X_1 \cap X_2 = \emptyset$ ?

Comment: Now the definition has been corrected.  The case I described above illustrated that the definition wasn't quite right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proof by contradiction.  Suppose that $[a,b]$ is not in $f(X)$.  Then there is some $c\in(a,b)$ such that $c\not\in f(X)$.  Let $X_1=(-\infty,c)$ and $X_2=(c,\infty)$.  Since $c\not\in f(X)$, it is clear that $f(X)\subseteq X_1\cup X_2$.

Now, consider $f^{-1}(X_1)$ and $f^{-1}(X_2)$.  Since $X_1$ and $X_2$ are open sets, their inverse images are open (using the definition of continuous).  Moreover, $X\subseteq f^{-1}(X_1)\cup f^{-1}(X_2)$, but these sets are disjoint.

Since $X$ is connected, it must be that one of them is equal to all of $X$.  This, however, is impossible because the preimage of $a$ is in $f^{-1}(X_1)$ and the preimage of $b$ is in $f^{-1}(X_2)$.

Comment: Here are you using the definition of continuous function with respect to topological spaces or the one for "ordinary" functions ? I'm confused which one is meant from the formulation.

Comment: I'm using the definition from topological spaces when I look at the preimages of open sets being open.

Comment: This is what makes me confused. Because nothing is being said about considering $\mathbb R$ as a topological space. And if it is implicit, how do I then know that the topology on $\mathbb R$ includes these two open sets ? Sorry, if I'm wrong - I'm new to the field.

Comment: When you say $f$ is continuous, you are implying that there is a topology on both spaces, and, moreover, that the preimage of open sets are open.

Comment: Yes, but the topology on $\mathbb R$ doesn't have to include open sets $(a,b)$ or does it ? Couldn't it be $\{\emptyset, [a,b], \mathbb R\}$ ? It it implicit that one always talk about the topology induced from the metric space ?

Comment: If you don't specify the topology, it's standard to assume the standard topology.  You're right that if you're using a different topology, then everything changes.  In fact, using the topology that you specify, the given statement is false!

Comment: Thank you Michael Burr, I will remember that it is implicit that one is always taking about the induced topology (w.r.t the Euclidean norm-metric) when talking about $\mathbb R$ as a topological space.

Answer (score 1):

proving by contradiction...suppose $c\in (a,b)$ is not in the image ...then consider $X_1$=$f^{-1} ((-\infty ,c))$ and $X_2 = f^{-1} ((c, \infty))$ both of these two sets are open since $f$ is continuous...then $X_1 \cup X_2 = X$ so one of these two sets has to be empty since $X$ is connected but they cannot be empty since $a\in f(X_1)$ and $b\in f(X_2)$ ...so contradiction

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider $f^{-1}((x,+\infty))$ and $f^{-1}((-\infty,x))$ for any $x\in(a,b)$.